# Retrieve value from a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
   [{'infoType': {'name': 'PERSON_NAME'}, 'count': '71'},
     {'infoType': {'name': 'LOCATION'}, 'count': '2'},
   ]
```

I would like to transform this list in order to get

```
   [{'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 
     'count': '71'},
     {'name': 'LOCATION', 
    'count': '2'},
   ]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What have you tried already based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
lst = [{'infoType': {'name': 'PERSON_NAME'}, 'count': '71'}, {'infoType': {'name': 'LOCATION'}, 'count': '2'}]
output = []
for d in lst:
    newDict = {}
    newDict['name'] = d['infoType']['name']
    newDict['count'] = d['count']
    output.append(newDict)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 'count': '71'}, 
 {'name': 'LOCATION', 'count': '2'}]
```